# VSCode remote Python virtual environment

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, python-venv, sshfs

Here is how the thing doesn't work:

The project source code is located on a remote machine. The Python virtual environment is installed in the project's root directory (using venv).

I sshfs the project folder and start local VSCode. It detects the virtual environment, but doesn't see pylint or other packages installed in it.

Python 3.6.7
  VS Code - latest version
  OSs - Debian 9 remote, Linux Mint 19 local
  Both sshfs connection and venv installation are performed under the same account.

Is there some special way a virtual environment should be set up to be usable remotely?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There were problems with sshfs in early VSCode versions, but recent distrib has [Remote Development](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-remote-release) extension that lets you develop your code via ssh.

Since you have activated your virtual environment, just get venv python path with `which python` command and copy it to the [Select Interpreter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) menu.

Answer (score 5):

Activate your python environment:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Find which python path you are using:

```
which python
```

Usually it is in :

```
venv/bin/python
```

Go to the bottom of VS Code, and click on the version number :

[image]

Click on Enter interpreter path... :
[image]

Enter the path you found above with the which python command.

Comment: When using VSCode 1.70.2 and ssh-ing to a remote machine, I do not see any number after 'Python', just 'Python' itself.

Comment: @ComputerScientist you can do `python --version` in that case